# How to add Css Class to item inside Ember's {{#each}} loop, according to index? - Ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a Ember app with side-menu.
The menu items in the html are based on Ember's {{each}} loop.
When user select a menu-item I want to add this item active class.

How do I add css class to single item inside Ember's {{each}}
According to condition from the controller.

Html/Hbs:

```
<ul>
   {{#each menuItem in sideMenuItems}}
      <li {{bind-attr class="isActive: active-class"}} {{ action 'selectMenuItem' _view.contentIndex }}>
         {{ menuItem.text }}
      </li>
   {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Controller:

```
Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  selectedMenuIndex: 0,
  isActive: function() {
    return (this.get('selectedMenuIndex') == ? ? ? );
  }.property('???'),

  actions: {
    selectMenuItem: function(itemIndex) {
      this.set('selectedMenuIndex', itemIndex);
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Which version of ember are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When user select a menu-item I want to add this item active class.

#### Since you are using Ember 1.5, I will first show you a few ways to achieve this for older versions.

The easiest way to do this is to add a flag `isActive` to the item itself, and use that as the condition for the css class. You can set the flag to `true` for the clicked item in your `selectMenuItem` action. If your logic allows only a single item to be active at a time, you must also reset any currently active item's `isActive` flags to `false`.

```
{{#each menuItem in sideMenuItems}}
  <li {{bind-attr class="menuItem.isActive:active-class"}} {{action 'selectMenuItem' _view.contentIndex}}>
     {{menuItem.text}}
  </li>
{{/each}}
```

Controller:

```
Ember.ObjectController.extend({

  sideMenuItems: // ... your array of items, each containing an isActive flag

  actions: {
    selectMenuItem: function(itemIndex) {
      var items = this.get('sideMenuItems');
      items.forEach(function(item, idx) {         // go through the items,
          if(idx === itemIndex) {                 // find the clicked item and set it as active
              Ember.set(item, 'isActive', true);
          } else {                                // reset all other items
              Ember.set(item, 'isActive', false);
          }
      });
    }
  }
})
```

A more efficient way would be to store the currently active item as a separate variable, this will remove the need to iterate the `sideMenuItems` array twice:

Controller:

```
Ember.ObjectController.extend({

  sideMenuItems: // ... your array of items, each containing an isActive flag
  activeMenuItem: null,

  actions: {
    selectMenuItem: function(itemIndex) {
      var items = this.get('sideMenuItems');
      var currActive = this.get('activeMenuItem');
      var nextActive = items.objectAt(itemIndex);

      // if there is a currently active item, deactivate it
      if(currActive) {
        Ember.set(currActive, 'isActive', false);
      }

      // if the user clicked on the currently active item, we just reset the selected item
      // otherwise we update the isActive flag for the clicked item
      if(currActive === nextActive) {
          nextActive = null;
      } else {
         Ember.set(nextActive, 'isActive', true);
      }

      // set the clicked item as the currently active menu item
      this.set('activeMenuItem', nextActive);
  }
})
```

---

Another way would be to create a custom component `menu-item` that renders your `li` item with/without a class depending on the active index.

```
Ember.Component.extend({

    // passed in
    activeIndex: -1,
    index: -1,
    selectMenuItemAction: '',

    // local
    tagName: 'li',
    classNameBindings: ['activeClass'],

    activeClass: function() {
        var idx = this.get('index');
        var activeIdx = this.get('activeIndex');

        // if the current item is the active index, return the active class
        if(idx === activeIdx) {
            return 'active-class';
        }

        // otherwise return no class
        return '';
    }.property('activeIndex')

    actions: {
        selectMenuItem: function() {
            this.sendAction('selectMenuItemAction', this.get('index'));
        }
    }
})
```

And then use it like:

```
{{#each menuItem in sideMenuItems}}
    {{#menu-item index=_view.contentIndex activeIndex=selectedMenuIndex selectMenuItemAction="selectMenuItem"}}
        {{menuItem.text}}
    {{/menu-item}}
{{/each}}
```

Controller:

```
Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  selectedMenuIndex: 0,

  actions: {
    selectMenuItem: function(itemIndex) {
      this.set('selectedMenuIndex', itemIndex);
    }
  }
})
```

---

Since using `_view.contentIndex` is sort of a hack, you can just pass the actual menu item instead and compare the object references instead of indexes to determine the active item:

Menu item component:

```
Ember.Component.extend({

    // passed in
    activeItem: null,
    item: null,
    selectMenuItemAction: '',

    // local
    tagName: 'li',
    classNameBindings: ['activeClass'],

    activeClass: function() {
        var item = this.get('item');
        var activeItem = this.get('activeItem');

        // if the current item is the active item, return the active class
        if(item === activeItem) {
            return 'active-class';
        }

        // otherwise return no class
        return '';
    }.property('activeItem')

    actions: {
        selectMenuItem: function() {
            this.sendAction('selectMenuItemAction', this.get('item'));
        }
    }
})
```

And then use it like:

```
{{#each menuItem in sideMenuItems}}
    {{#menu-item item=menuItem activeItem=selectedMenuItem selectMenuItemAction="selectMenuItem"}}
        {{menuItem.text}}
    {{/menu-item}}
{{/each}}
```

Controller:

```
Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  selectedMenuItem: null,

  actions: {
    selectMenuItem: function(item) {
      this.set('selectedMenuItem', item);
    }
  }
})
```

#### Here's a much easier way to do this in Ember > 1.13

Ember > 1.13 supports inline helpers so you can achieve this pretty much how you want it. Ember CLI 1.13 also comes with [babel](https://babeljs.io/) so we can use ES6 as well which allows for further simplifications:

Controller:

```
Ember.Controller.extend({
  selectedMenuIndex: 0,
  menuItems: // ...
  actions: {
    selectMenuItem(itemIndex) {
      this.set('selectedMenuIndex', itemIndex);
    }
  }
});
```

Template:

```
{{#each menuItems as |item index|}}
  <li class="{{active-class index selectedMenuIndex}}" {{action "selectMenuItem" index}}>
  {{item.text}}
  </li>
{{/each}}
```

Helper:

```
activeClass(params) {
  const [ index, active ] = params; // use ES6 destructuring
  return (index === active) ? 'active-class': '';
}
```

[Here is a working twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/d2ff4a2b862a6fbf4056)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Indeed your method will work. But does Ember.js have any better way dealing with this situation? Similar to Angular.js ng-class="{isActive: $index==selectedIndex}". I know that Ember don't support inline condition inside the html, this is why Ember uses property() functions inside the controller. So can I write a property() function with this condition?

Comment: Check out my edits. You can make a component to do this.

Comment: If you can update to the newest Ember, it contains many many improvements and it will make your life easier. I attached a way to achieve this in the newest Ember.

Comment: As far as your question about using `property()`, it would be pretty much the same as in my first couple examples. Using the first example,  if you move the `items.forEach(...` code (inside the controller) from the `selectMenuItem` action to a separate computed property that recomputes when `selectedMenuIndex` changes (i.e. `.property('selectedMenuIndex')`, you would achieve what you are asking, although the behavior wouldn't really differ from my example.